# QT doesn't create .pro file?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I downloaded and installed QT 5.3 and i just can't use it, because it gives me error like this :

```
    Cannot find file: C:\Users\Çağrı\Desktop\C++\qt\untitled4\untitled4.pro.
12:51:07: The process "C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\qmake.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled4 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

I tried everything i know but it's still same.

Any ideas ?

Comment: how do you create this project?

Comment: i checkhed again actually it exists but what is problem then ?

Comment: Try creating it in another directory outside your home directory, to check if it chokes on your username `Çağrı`